# Escaping in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, escaping

Hi I am tring to fire this query

```
update txnblackout
  set enddate= ''TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')''
  where idsequence='1'
```

But it is not working giving error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Can you please justify it. Why it is happening?

This is the java code i am using to create query  : -

```
Map<String, String> l_script_columns = new HashMap<String, String>();
        l_script_columns.put("startdate", "'TO_DATE('"
            + txtStartDate.getText().trim() + "','"
            + FieldMapperHelper.DATE_Format + "')'");
```

please let me know if you want more clarification.Thanks.

Comment: Is the data type of the enddate column in table txnblackout DATE?

Comment: Yes.Here David.I just want to know why update txnblackout
  set enddate= ''TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')''
  where idsequence='1' is not working even i have escaped all the single quotes.

Comment: You haven't escaped all the single quotes. But even if you had, that would give a quoted string containing 'TO_DATE' etc and not the value you wanted. I don't know Java, but surely it has a way to pass a date value as a bind variable? (btw date literals can be written more succinctly as `date '2012-02-25'`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why ever are you doing the escaping?

```
with txnblackout as 
       (select trunc(sysdate + level) enddate /* trunc drops time component */ , level idsequence
          from dual
       connect by level <= 10 /* this will generate 10 rows with an incrementing 'level' value */ )
select enddate
     , idsequence
  from txnblackout
 where enddate = to_date('20/10/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')
;
```

thus you should be safe to drop the extra quotes, they are not necessary.

```
update txnblackout
  set enddate= TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')
  where idsequence=1;
```

(note this assumes idsequence is a number)

---

At the end of the day, if you are passing in a non-parameterized dynamic sql query into Oracle, you'll need it to look like this:

```
"update txnblackout   
    set enddate= TO_DATE(''25/02/2012'',''dd/mm/yyyy'')  
  where idsequence=1;"
```

*(please note I am still assuming that idsequence is a NUMBER type and not a varchar)*

Check this out though, try to be safe!

You also won't have to worry about escaping if you parameterize it!

[Preventing SQL Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Comment: I am escaping date because i am executing query by java code and there it is automatically putting single code just before to TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy') so to escape this i put one extra single quote.But that is not working.

Comment: @Sunil, you should be using parameterized queries here.  but not going into that.  the only strings you need to worry about escaping you already have -- but the "to_date" should not be incased in any quotes; I'll post an edit to this that ought to get you on the correct track.  But I strongly suggest using parameterized queries and NOT using dynamic SQL to keep your site safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your query above you want to keep the date or the text, so in the first case

```
    update txnblackout 
        set enddate= TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')
      where idsequence='1'
```

The id sequence being text or number doesn't matter, in the second case you want to keep the text:

```
     update txnblackout 
        set enddate= 'TO_DATE(''25/02/2012'',''dd/mm/yyyy'')'
      where idsequence='1'
```

I think you want the first case please check.
Best regards

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.Here 'To_DATE' is a function, i am using to save my date into a particular format. Column enddate is of type Date So i can't use second case and I am executing my query by java code and java code explicitly putting a single code just before to TO_DATE function so i put one extra single quote to escape single quote but that is not working.

Comment: So that is a Java String issue.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to try this one:

```
Map<String, String> l_script_columns = new HashMap<String, String>();
        l_script_columns.put("startdate", "'||TO_DATE('"
            + txtStartDate.getText().trim() + "','"
            + FieldMapperHelper.DATE_Format + "')||'");
```

then final result will be:

```
update txnblackout 
    set enddate= ''||TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')||''
  where idsequence='1'
```

Comment: Won't that implicitly convert it back to a string? I suppose you may get away with it because Oracle will then convert that back to a date using the same default date format, but all the same it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ';' at the end of your command...

You command should look like : 
`update txnblackout
  set enddate= ''TO_DATE('25/02/2012','dd/mm/yyyy')''
  where idsequence='1';`